# How to use jQuery UI datepicker.format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

The following results in: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatDate' of undefined`
I have all three files in the same directory (jquery, jquery-ui and this html file):

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"</script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $t = $.datepicker.formatDate("M dd", new Date("2014-12-01"));
  console.log($t);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your actual HTML, you should change

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"</script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"</script>
```

into

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what the difference between these notes?

Comment: @AlexFilatov the opening script tags are closed in the second version

Answer (score 1):

You aren't loading the jquery-ui properly.  You need a closing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

I sloved the same error by using the FULL datepicker js file

```
<script src="/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
```

available in 
[Git Datetimepicker/build/](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/tree/master/build)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="your_input" name="your_input" />
```

JS:

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#your_input" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

Optional Fast load datapicker:

```
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $('body').on('focus',"#your_input", function(){
              $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
        });
      });
      </script>
```